# Google Data studios

Tags: google-drive-realtime-api, looker-studio, google-drive-shared-drive

I just wanted to ask if there was a way of of publishing live data on google docs with data studios on a password restricted site? (Without it being visible online to all users).

Users would log in through multiple domains emails such as gmail or company domains. So this would need to be considered.

Please message a potential solution to this issue. Further information can be provided.

Thank you.

TS.

Answer (score 0):

first **lets look at the question about embedding**, if you mean Google Data Studio dashboard it can be embeded to any site. Its up to you if it will be hidden behind log in gate you created or accessed anonymously. Problem is someone can copy paste the code from the embed code, so its better to use in-build Share function which will ask for Google Login and will allow only users which the dashboard is shared with.

About **the live data problem** it really depends on the type of data source and its connection. Google Data studio as such is not using any data warehouse just a small cache so the data source is pinged everytime you open the dashboard. This has benefits and downsides. Benefit it your case is that the data is always live if the source is live. Downside is if the datasource is dead, google data studio dont have any data to show and will report error (biggest difference in comparison with Microsoft Power BI, which is actually saving the data to Microsoft Cloud.

In plain words: google analytics, google adwords, database connections, will be always live (the delay is usually few minutes).

You were asking about google documents, these will be always "live", everytime you open Google Data Studio it will check the connected documents for the data, but depends, how you update the data in them, if you do it manually or you have some Apps Script to help you.

**Did I answered you question? Do you need other help?**